# How to migrate WidgetKit extensions from dual-target to single-target watchOS app?

Tags: watchkit, watchos, widgetkit

Is there a way to migrate WidgetKit extensions made using dual-target watchOS apps to single-target apps? When you create a widget extension with a dual-target app, the bundle identifier includes the extra extension domain (com.company.app.watchkitapp.**watchkitextension**.widgets). When Xcode 15 migrates a dual-target to single-target, it removes “.watchkitextension” from both the watchOS app bundle identifier and the widget extension bundle identifier. watchOS seems to handle migrating the main app just fine, but any complications created with the dual-target do not get migrated and are just blank until the user re-configures, which would be a huge bummer to have to ship. If I try to manually set the bundle identifier back to include “.watchkitextension”, the OS rejects the installation because of the extraneous dot after the parent app’s prefix.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided any code, so it is a little difficult to help out.

However, do you have both ClockKit and WidgetKit complications in your App? In watchOS 10 ClockKit complications were deprecated, and the replacement is WidgetKit complications. You might be running into this issue.

[This document from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3157-updating-your-watchos-project-for-swiftui-and-widgetkit) talks about running a CLKComplicationWidgetMigrator, not sure if that will help at all?

Comment: No, never shipped any ClockKit complications, strictly WidgetKit. There isn't any code-related problem here to my knowledge, this is just about how the system treats dual-target to single-target watch app migrations and the accompanying bundle identifier changes.